# How do I write a Powershell script that checks when the last time a file was added to a folder?

Tags: powershell, loops, recursion, foreach, report

I'm currently writing a script that checks each folder in a directory for the last time a file was written to each folder. I'm having trouble figuring out how to obtain the last time a file was written to the folder, as opposed to just retrieving the folder's creation date.

I've tried using Poweshell's recursive method, but couldn't figure out how to properly set it up. Right now, the script successfully prints the name of each folder to the Excel spreadsheet, and also print the last write time of each folder, which is the incorrect information.

```
$row = 2

$column = 1

Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Sylveon\Desktop\Test"| ForEach-Object {     

    #FolderName
    $sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column) = $_.Name
    $column++
    #LastBackup
    $sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column) = $_.LastWriteTime
    $column++
    #Increment to next Row and reset Column
    $row++
    $column = 1
}
```

The current state of the script prints each folder name to the report, but gives the folders creation date rather than the last time a file was written to that folder.

Comment: Are you sure that items have been added to the directory since they have been created? I have loads of folders that have really old lastwritetime values because they never get used

Comment: I posted an answer that addresses how do get the latest date an item in a folder was edited, but I'm pretty sure that's not a complete answer. What exactly do you want your Excel spreadsheet to look like when you're done - that date for each directory in a given directory? - or are you just using the spreadsheet to see what your script is returning?

Comment: I think I understand what you're going for, check my edited answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only looking at the first level of files in each folder, you can do it using a nested loop:

```
$row = 2
$column = 1

$folders = Get-ChildItem $directorypath
ForEach ($folder in $folders) { 

    # start off with LastEdited set to the last write time of the folder itself
    $LastEdited = $folder.LastWriteTime
    $folderPath = $directoryPath + '\' + $folder.Name
    # this 'dynamically' sets each folder's path

    $files = Get-Childitem $folderPath
    ForEach ($file in $files) {
        if ((Get-Date $file.LastWriteTime) -gt (Get-Date $LastEdited)) {
            $LastEdited = $file.LastWriteTime
        }
    }

    $sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column) = $folder.Name
    $column++
    $sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column) = $LastEdited
    $row++
    $column = 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should work to get the most recent edit date of any file in the current directory.

```
Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -first 1 -ExpandProperty "LastWriteTime"
```

`Get-ChildItem` gets items in your directory

`Sort-Object` `-Property LastWriteTime` `-Descending` sorts by write-time, latest first

`Select-Object` `-first 1` `-ExpandProperty "LastWriteTime"` gets the first one in the list, then gets its write-time

---

I made this to get the data you're trying to get. The last line gives us an empty string if the directory is empty, which is probably what's safest for Excel, but you could also default to something other than an empty string, like the directory's creation date:

```
$ChildDirs = Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] }
$EditNames = $ChildDirs | ForEach-Object Name
$EditTimes = $EditNames | ForEach-Object { @( (Get-ChildItem $_ | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -first 1 LastWriteTime), '' -ne $null)[0] }

for($i=0; $i -lt $ChildDirs.Length; $i++) {
    Write-Output $EditNames[$i]
    Write-Output $EditTimes[$i]
}
```

---

To implement this for what you're doing, if I understand your question correctly, try the following:

```
$ChildDirs = Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] }
$EditNames = $ChildDirs | ForEach-Object Name
$EditTimes = $EditNames | ForEach-Object { @( (Get-ChildItem $_ | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -first 1 LastWriteTime), '' -ne $null)[0] }

for($i=0; $i -lt $ChildDirs.Length; $i++) {
    #FolderName
    $sheet.Cells.Item($row, $column) = $EditNames[$i]
    $column++
    #LastBackup
    $sheet.Cells.Item($row, $column) = $EditTimes[$i]
    $row++
    $column = 1
}
```